# Quiero darle valor al atributo mediante un metodo

Tags: java

Tengo la clase DNI, con get&set y un metodo, obtenerLetra:

```
public class DNI {
private int numero;
//La letra, va a ser la que el metodo calcule.
private String letra;

**//Constructor donde dudo como se hace**
public DNI(int numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
    this.letra = getLetra();
}


public void setNumero(int numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public void setLetra(String letra) {
    this.letra = letra;
}

public int getNumero() {
    return numero;
}
public String getLetra() {
    return letra;
}

public String obtenerLetra(int numero) {
    //Compruebo que la longitud de numero sea mayor a 8
    String numS = Integer.toString(numero);
    if(numS.length()!=8) {
        System.out.println("El dni debe tener 8 digitos");
    }else {
        //Letra es la letra que vamos ha adjuntar
        String letra;
        //Array de las letras
        String [] letras = {"T","R","W","A","G","M","Y","F","P","D","X","B","N","J","Z","S","Q","V","H","L","C","K","E"};
        //Va a contener la suma del numero
        int operacion = 0;
        operacion = numero%23;
        letra = letras[operacion];
        return letra;
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

Ahora, desde la clase Main, hago un objeto de DNI, y quiero que se construya con la letra, pero que yo solo meta el numero. ¿Es posible?

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo por qué si ya tienes un método `getLetra` pretendes tener otro `obtenerLetra`... ¿cuál sería la diferencia entre ambos? Hay más cosas que debo criticar de tu clase, si es una sola letra, el tipo de dato debería ser `Char` y  sería en el *setter*  o en el constructor donde deberías controlar que el DNI no tuviese más de una letra al inicio. Creo que te ahogas en un vaso de agua creando la clase de la forma en que lo estás haciendo. Yo pasaría el DNI completo al constructor y ahí haría la validación y una eventual asignación a la propiedad `letra` de la clase.

Comment: Quiero, que al llamar al constructor, solo pasarle el numero, y que al hacer getLetra, me devuelva la letra que corresponde al dni. He hecho los cambios de private, de char, y del constructor, y ahora, en Main, al crear el objeto con el numero, y luego, imprimir getLetra, funciona. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Perdona, no me detuve a leer bien la pregunta. Si es así, la respuesta de @ElliotRG se aproxima a lo que quieres. Aunque persisto en declarar letra como `Char` y deberías quitar el *setLetra*  si la misma se debe asignar de una forma aleatoria. Dejando el *setter* permitirías que alguien altere ese valor el cual debe asignarlo la clase. Aunque deberías explicar si hay algún criterio en específico para asignar la letra o si esta se asigna sin más de una forma totalmente aleatoria ¿?

Answer (score 1):

La definición de tu clase parece correcta pero falla el constructor.

Al darle valor al atributo *letra* debes llamar al método *obtenerLetra*, que si sólo pretende ser usado en la creación de un DNI, debería ser un método privado.

Con lo que tu constructor quedaría tal que así:

```
public DNI(int numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
    this.letra = obtenerLetra(numero);
}
```

Y la definición del método debería corregirse a:

```
private String obtenerLetra(int numero)
```

Un saludo.